# Trigger Twilio through API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to make Twilio call my phone number based on my API request. Found this article [Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API) and sent similar request using curl:

```
curl -X POST https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Executions \
--data-urlencode "To=+13105555555" \
--data-urlencode "From=+12125551234" \
-u "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token"
```

This is my flow:
[image]

I expected that Twilio would use related number ("From", which I have bought in Twilio) to call my "To" number. But nothing happens.

Is it even possible to trigger Twilio like this to call me? I have only number which is voice enabled (not allowing sms), so cannot trigger it with message.

*EDIT* Corrected From and To explanation based on one of answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, did you make sure to publish your Studio Flow? Also, check the Debugger for any error messages and view the Studio Execution logs (left side of the screen when in Studio) for any hints. If this is a trial account, you can only call numbers you have previously verified as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alan, I've Published this already and my call number is verified. But thanks for mentioning Studio Execution logs. Now i see its showing error ```Failure connecting call: 'Account not authorized to call +48xxxxxxxxx. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/geo-permissions/low-risk'``` I'll check it now and let know if i'll figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Adding +48 country code here ```https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/geo-permissions/low-risk``` solved the issue. Bot just called me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up `From` and `To`.

`To` is the number being called.

`From` is the number from which is being called, this would need to be the number you purchased for it in Twilio.

Comment: Yup, you are right, I have messed this up. Correcting the post now. Still, problem still exists.

Comment: OK, as @Alan mentioned have you checked the Twilio Debugger for any error messages? Also does the `curl` request return correctly with a `200`? What does the returned JSON look like?

Comment: Hi @yvesonline, thanks for help, eventually looking at the Studio Logs navigated me to the issue.